# Swift 5 UIImagePickerController is not getting called

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimagepicker

I have the most standard/out of the box code for calling the delegate function in UIImagePicker:

import Foundation
    import UIKit
    //import UIKit.UIImage

```
class FirstViewController:
      UIViewController
    , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var bigImageView: UIImageView!

    var newlyPickedImage: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = Color.offWhiteLight

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTapImageView))
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    }

    @objc func onTapImageView(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(
         _ picker: UIImagePickerController
        , didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
    {
        print("assert enter function") /// not entered

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.bigImageView.image = pickedImage
            print("picked image: \(pickedImage)")
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The issue is that `func imagePickerController` is not getting called. This is odd because in a different view the exact code does call `func imagePickerController`. I have also tried instantiating a global `UIImagePickerController` instance in the Appdelegate and referencing that, the call is still not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing setting delegate for the `UIImagePickerController`. Replace your `onTapImageView` with this:

```
@objc func onTapImageView(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Also you need the controller to confirm to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` so add conformance to `FirstViewController` like this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```